# How to replace " " " with ""

Tags: java, html, file-io

So I want to replace all `"` from a file my java code is reading with nothing. Just so the all the " get removed and i can write the information i want. For example the file contains:

```
<span class="positive">This is the text i want</span>
```

How to i remove the `"postive"`?

This is my code:

```
public static void writeTXT(String j) throws IOException {

    j = j.replaceAll(">", "");
    j = j.replaceAll("<", "");
    for (int i = 0;i < REPLACE.length;i++) {
        j = j.replace(REPLACE[i], "");
    }


public final static String[] REPLACE = {
    "onth Change <span class=\"stay\">",
    "/span/li"
};
```

Comment: It's really unclear exactly what you're asking, but it *seems* like you're trying to parse and extract things from HTML, and you should use an XML parser for that.

Comment: You may be interested in looking into JSoup... it's a very easy to use HTML parser for Java. http://jsoup.org/

Comment: He just want to remove a text between `" "`

Comment: @MarcoAcierno yes but relying on a regex for this will likely lead to error. Using a parser like JSoup to take care of this is super easy, and error free.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno No, what it looks like is that the OP wants to end up with "This is the text I want" and they're jumping through all kinds of hoops to get there instead of using an XML parser.

Comment: @BrianRoach "How to i remove the "postive"?" i see this question

Comment: @MarcoAcierno it's very easy with JSoup -- it's why it was created, exactly for the purpose the OP has in mind --  http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html

Comment: @MarcoAcierno And then apparently stopped reading there instead of looking at the code and what it's doing.

Comment: @BrianRoach Maybe his code is wrong? If he know how to do what he wants he do it instead of post it. P.S I'm not saying you can use regex for xml/html parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do is to parse HTML with regex. Only Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regular expressions.

If you want to get this substring, you need to write your own parser which analyze string letter-by-letter, or use an existing one to parse HTML.

Comment: Or, use an already built and extremely good HTML parser for Java like JSoup. Don't re-invent the wheel, you will do it wrong.

Comment: While I agree with your statement, only Chuck Norris can _properly_ parse HTML with regex, the questions is still valid, people often use regexes to extract data out of HTML, not to fully parse it.

Comment: @JuanMendes the only way to property do this, and ensure it's always accurate, it to use JSoup. Using a regex for this will cause errors. If the OP is writing code to parse only 1 specific html page that will never ever change, then sure, write a regex. otherwise, use a parser and with a few commands like; `Element positiveClass = doc.select("span.positive").first();` he can be on his way.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I'm not saying an XML parser is not better, I'm saying that if the HTML is under your control, a regex may be able to do the job

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that you should use an XML parser for extracting text out of HTML, the following code will remove everything between double quotes

```
    String html = "<span class=\"positive\">This is the text i want</span>";
    System.out.println( html.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"", "\"\"" ));
    // <span class="">This is the text i want</span>
```